# Cumulative aggregates produce a token unknown error

Tags: sum, firebird

I have a problem with Firebird (embedded - version 3.0) database with cumulative aggregates. I have the following table:

```
+----+---------+
|ID  |Salary   +
+----+---------+
|1   |10.00    |
+----+---------+
|2   |20.00    |
+----+---------+
|3   |35.00    |
+----+---------+
|4   |10.00    |
+----+---------+
```

I would like to add a third column (cum_sum) that will contain a cumulative sum, i.e .:

```
+----+---------+---------+
|ID  +Salary   +cum_sum  |
+----+---------+---------+
|1   |10.00    |10.00    |
+----+---------+---------+
|2   |20.00    |30.00    |
+----+---------+---------+
|3   |35.00    |65.00    |
+----+---------+---------+
|4   |10.00    |75.00    |
+----+---------+---------+
```

When I try to use the following code:

```
select id, salary, sum(salary) over (order by salary) cum_sum
  from employee
  order by salary
```

I get a message:

```
Invalid token.
Dynamic SQL Error.
SQL error code = -104.
Token unknown - line 1, column 37.
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: Which Firebird version are you using? Window functions were introduced in Firebird 3. Also not that your error message is incomplete, Firebird normally also reports the invalid token (in this case `(`).

Comment: I had read over the fact you say you are using Firebird 3 Embedded. I suggest you double check, because the error suggests otherwise. Try executing `select rdb$get_context('SYSTEM', 'ENGINE_VERSION') from rdb$database` to retrieve the actual version.

Comment: Minor nitpick: the expected output suggest you want to use `order by id` both in the window and in the main select.

Comment: this query is but verbatim copy of one from Firebird 3.0.0 Release Notes (page 77), so I think it can not give error in FB3. Either different server version or different query or different error it must be.

Comment: @Arioch'The You're right, but I can reproduce the exact same error message with Firebird 2.5 (that is why I knew the invalid token was `(`).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel he might be using some much older client library though, that has less parameters in the `firebird.msg` template for this particular error. Especially if he maybe always used embedded versions and now just tried to upgrade it. One might even find when the error template was extended to include the very token, but I guess that has little practical value :-) P.S. or indeed TS could just no recognize the parenthesis was part of error message and cut it away when copypasting.

Comment: @Arioch'The Having an older firebird.msg would just give an error about an unknown error code, not a token unknown. And I already remarked that the expected output does not match the query (I tested the query on FB 3 and it works).

Answer (score 1):

You get this error if you are using Firebird 2.5 or earlier. Window functions were [introduced in Firebird 3](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/release_notes/html/en/3_0/rlsnotes30.html#rnfb30-dml-windowfuncs). You will need to upgrade to Firebird 3 if you want to run the query as shown in your question.

As you claim to use Firebird 3 Embedded, I suggest that you carefully check

1. if your Firebird embedded version is actually version 3 (eg use `select rdb$get_context('SYSTEM', 'ENGINE_VERSION') from rdb$database`; this works for Firebird 2.1 and higher and will report an error for earlier versions).

   You may have loaded a different version of Firebird. This can happen if you have a different version of the embedded library earlier on the search path. This can also happen if you have a Firebird 2.5 fbembed.dll and a Firebird 3 fbclient.dll in the same location. In Firebird 3, embedded was unified with the normal client, and no longer has a separate library (it requires *additional* libraries, the engine plugin, instead). However most Firebird drivers will first attempt to load fbembed.dll before falling back to fbclient.dll.
2. if you are actually connecting with Firebird embedded, and not accidentally to a Firebird server instance of a different version (eg `select rdb$get_context('SYSTEM', 'NETWORK_PROTOCOL') from rdb$database` will report `NULL` for embedded, but a value for other connection methods).

   This can happen if you use the wrong connection string or otherwise incorrectly configured your driver.

Otherwise, if you can't upgrade, you will need to use the more painful option of writing a stored procedure (or block) that does this for you, or resort to equally painful recursive CTE-based solutions (that have other limitations that might get in the way).